# How to hide axis name when axis is hidden echarts

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

When removing all values from legend, the y-axis is hidden, but the name isn't, how can I hide it as well?

Or maybe stop the x-axis from expanding could help, since the axis label is truncating.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Their is no option to hide the name of an axis.

Instead set the [xAxis.name](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.name) and/or [yAxis.name](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.name) to a null value, or unset the property.